# Some small issue in getting the associated model data in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 models product and image. Product has an Has-many relationship with Image. I want to fetch both products and images records based on product id.So I have written the query like this

```
$this->Product->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('product_id'=>230));
```

I am getting all product table entries but not image tables records. I checked with var_dump(), then images table entries are coming like this

```
array('Images =>
    array
      0 => 
        array
          ...
      1 => 
        array
          ... );
```

What might be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Pushpa

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're doing here; $this->Product->find(...) cannot return an array('Images' => ''). Also, if you're looking to fetch one product only (that's what you want, right?), it would seem that you'd select on 'id' => 230 rather than 'product_id' => 230 (naming convention). Please clarify.

Comment: you should ALWAYS use Model.field to make it clear when reading and make sure cake is working the way you want. With cake you should get something like array ( 'Product'=> array(.....), 'Images'=> array(0=>array(....), 1=>array(...)) that is cake normal behaviour. So what would be the problem? no image data? no product data? please clarify so we can help you better. Also i suggest you accept the answers in your other questions so people have their reward for their answers ;)

Comment: @Elte : Thanks, product_id is my foreign key reference.

Comment: @pushpa how can product_id be a foreign key to itself? in your code you're doing the find on Product.

Comment: @api55: Thanks for your suggestion, I am getting product data but not image data. Query is working good for find('first') condition, but it is not working for find('all') condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Product->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Product.id' => 230), 
    'recursive'  => 1 // ensures we are retrieving related models
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks Ivo, I want to get all records with product_id =230, so i tried with $this->Product->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Product.id=>'=230),'recursive'=>1));                        But this wasn't work.